# push notification not delivering on multiple devices in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to broadcast push message to multiple devices. Currently I am able to send messages if there are only 2 (might 1 or 2) device tokens stored in the database table. For 3 or more device tokens, I am not able to send the push messages. It even doesn't send messages to the previously added 2 devices. At the sever side I can see the messages as delivered, but they are not actually delivered.

I tested it on developer profile as well as on distribution profile, but on both I can only send messages if there are only 1 or 2 devices saved in DB table.

In both cases I used a single app id, which is configured for development and distribution.

My server side php code is as follows :

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
 include 'classfiles/Tokens.php';

if(isset($_POST))
{

$sender = $_POST['sender'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$token = new Tokens;
$arrtokens = $token->getTokens();


$devicetoken = $_POST['device_token'];

// Settings
$apnsCert = 'test.pem';//To be changed
$apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';//To be changed
$apnsPort = 2195;

// Connect to Apple Push Notification server
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'test123');
//60 -> timeout in seconds
$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $streamContext);
if (!$apns) {
    die('Error creating ssl socket');
}

stream_set_blocking ($apns, 0);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

if(is_array($arrtokens))
{
    //foreach($arrtokens as $key=>$deviceToken)
    for($i=0;$i<count($arrtokens);$i++)
    {

        $incrementcount = 0;
        $tokenid = $arrtokens[$i][0];
        $badgecount = $arrtokens[$i][1];
        $incrementcount = $badgecount+1;

        // Prepare payload
        $payload = 
        array(
            'aps' => array(
            'alert' => $message,
            'badge' => $incrementcount,
            'sound' => 'default',
            'sender' => $sender
            )
        );
        $payload = json_encode($payload);

   /*
        // this was also working 

        $apnsMessage =
            chr(1)
            . pack('N', 88)
            . pack('N', time() + 86400)
            . chr(0) . chr(32) 
            . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $tokenid)) 
            . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) 
            . $payload . $payload;
   */

        $apnsMessage = chr(0) .pack('n',32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $tokenid)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        // this was also working
        //   $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $tokenid)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        // this was also working
        //  $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device_tokens_array[i])) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;

      //  $result =fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);



            $result = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage, strlen($apnsMessage));



        if(!$result)
        {
            echo 'Message to the device ' . $arrtokens[$i][0] . ' not delivered' . '<br/>';
        }else
        {
            $token->updateToken($tokenid,$incrementcount);  
            echo 'Message to the device ' . $arrtokens[$i][0] . ' successfully delivered' . '<br/>';

        }


    //  sleep(10);


    }
}
else if($devicetoken != "")
{
    $apnsMessage = 
            chr(1)
            . pack('N', 88)
            . pack('N', time() + 86400)
            . chr(0) . chr(32) 
            . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) 
            . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) 
            . $payload . $payload;

    $result = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
    if(!$result)
        echo 'Message to the device ' . $token . ' not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo 'Message to the device ' . $token . ' successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
}


usleep(500000);

fclose($apns);

}

function checkAppleErrorResponse($apns)
{
$responseBinary = fread($apns, 6);
if ($responseBinary !== false && strlen($responseBinary) == 6)
{
    print(
        "\n"
        .'Error message recieved from Apple.'."\n"
        .'For the meaning, refer to: "Provider Communication with Apple Push Notification Service"'."\n"
    );
    $response = unpack('Ccommand/Cstatus_code/Nidentifier', $responseBinary);
    var_dump($response);
}
}

?>
```

And my client side code is here :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"error : %@", [error description]);
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
NSLog(@"deviceToken : %@", deviceToken);

NSString *myDeviceToken = [[[deviceToken description]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] 
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""];

NSLog(@"%@",myDeviceToken);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myDeviceToken forKey:@"myDeviceToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
NSString        *urlString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", tokenApi, myDeviceToken];//deviceToken
urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSLog(@"URL : %@", urlString);
NSURL           *url        = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest    *request    = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) {
    NSLog(@"UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone");
} else if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) {
    NSLog(@"UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert");
} else if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge) {
    NSLog(@"UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge");
} else if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound) {
    NSLog(@"UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound");
}

UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
int batchNo = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber];

if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    NSLog(@"applicationIconBadgeNumber : %d", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"sender"]
                                                     message:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]
                                                    delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    batchNo     = 0;
} else {
    NSLog(@"applicationIconBadgeNumber : %d", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:batchNo - 1];
    batchNo     = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber];
}


NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myDeviceToken"];
receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
NSString        *urlString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@&count=% d", updateTokenApi, token,batchNo];//deviceToken
urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSLog(@"URL : %@", urlString);
NSURL           *url        = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest    *request    = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];

//    NSLog(@"userInfo : %@", userInfo);
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"alerts"]];
//    NSLog(@"Before : %@", array);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm a"];

NSMutableArray *alertarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
[alertarray addObject:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
[alertarray addObject:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"sender"]];
[alertarray addObject:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]];
[array addObject:alertarray];

NSArray *alertsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:alertsArray forKey:@"alerts"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

[[[[self accountPage] accountHistoryPage] alertsArray] removeAllObjects];
[[[[self accountPage] accountHistoryPage] alertsArray] addObjectsFromArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"alerts"]];
[[[[self accountPage] accountHistoryPage] accountDetailTableView] reloadData];


//     NSLog(@"After : %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"alerts"]);
}
```

Comment: You should go back and accept the answers to questions you previously asked. As for this question, are all of the registered devices in production mode (did they download the app from the App Store)?

Comment: 1 of them are in development mode and other 4 devices in production mode. and the app is not downloaded from app store, we are testing the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the 3rd device token is invalid. If you send to this device token first, Apple close the socket and the messages to the other two devices are ignored, even if they seem to be delivered successfully at the server side.
If you are mixing development and production device tokens, that would explain why some of them are invalid. If you use a production certificate to open the socket to the APNS server, only production device tokens are valid for that connection (and vice versa).

Comment: now i have created new certificate, ne developer profile, new app id and now i m testing on 4 devices, it says dilivered to all devices but it send to only 1 device which is first one.

Comment: Are you using the enhanced format? Are you trying to read the error responses returned by Apple? It's possible that one of the device tokens you are using is invalid. It's still possible that some of the 4 device tokens are development tokens while the others are production tokens, which would explain the problem. Perhaps you shuold delete the device tokens from your database and get new tokens from the 4 devices, to make sure that they are all valid.

Comment: i created new app id, new developer profile and some changes on server side its working now (the commented lines i uncommented). I think you are right for developer and distribution token id. I also removed all entries in table. Thanks Eran.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day!